# Como capturar StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Olá,

Estou passando alguns problemas no servidor e com a aplicação desenvolvida em MVC...

Verifiquei que o site estava reiniciando o pool da aplicação sozinho, então fui no Event Viweer e percebi que a aplicação está sofrendo StackOverFlowException em alguma rotina (que não consegui mapear ainda).

Certo, sabendo disso criei um log de requests para obter as urls que acessavam e assim tentar achar a causa do problema *debugando*, porém, não consegui achar a causa principal, porque mesmo debugando o sistema pelo localhost e apontando para o banco de produção não ocorre esse StackOverFlowException. Gravo o log em um arquivo .txt antes de entrar em cada action (é desta forma que estou tentando descobrir a rotina que está causando o problema).

Preciso saber de uma forma de capturar essa exceção e descobrir em qual trecho do sistema está ocorrendo este problema.

OBS: 
• A aplicação é desenvolvida em MVC.
• Utiliza ***AutoMapper*** (acredito que tenha algo a ver, já que tenho que converter para uma ViewModel/DTO cada objeto e exibir na tela as informações). 
• Está alocado em um servidor IIS

**Atualização 01/06/2017**

Utilizei o Elmah, porém não funcionou a maneira que criava o *log*, pois o pool caía e creio que a versão do Elmah armazenava em memória. Descobri o problema ao entrar em uma página do sistema de forma local e a aplicação cair.

A razão pelo ***StackoverflowException*** se dava pelo fato de utilizar dois atributos de roteamento na mesma Controller`:

```
[RoutePrefix("exemplo")]
[Route("{action}"]
public class TesteController : Controller 
{
    ....
}
```

Retirei o segundo atributo e o problema sumiu.

O mais engraçado é que está configuração já estava há um bom tempo antes mesmo de eu assumir o projeto. Percebi que também ocorria de forma randômica, pois entrava normalmente em todas as actions desta Controller.

Comment: "acredito que tenha algo a ver, já que tenho que converter para uma ViewModel/DTO cada objeto e exibir na tela as informações". Por que?

Comment: Boa noite, no caso o AutoMapper me deu alguns problemas de referência circular, assim, uma entidade acaba mapeando outra e gera o Overflow. É claro, não é o AutoMapper em si que é o problema, mas a forma que devo estar utilizando ele. Tenho muitas classes mapeadas e eu acho que vai ser um trabalho árduo descobrir qual desses mapeamentos está dando problema.

Comment: Não, não. Eu perguntei por que você precisa "converter para uma ViewModel/DTO cada objeto", porque não precisa não.

Comment: Utilizam um sistema interno para gerarem as tabelas do Banco de Dados, também tem uma nomenclatura na qual cada campo devem ter menos de letras e acaba gerando uma grande confusão. Além disto, a maioria dos campos de todas as tabelas são 'nullables'. A maioria das tabelas possuem campos inutilizados, então eu jogo somente os campos que preciso nas View Models (apesar de poder fazer isso diretamente nas entidades raízes). Preferi fazer desta forma, acredito que foi um erro. Estou esperando a oportunidade de reformular este sistema, mas este erro apareceu e é prioridade corrigi-lo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um método mais eficiente para capturar a exceção (e a *Stack Trace* toda) é [usando o ELMAH](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/).

Procure também publicar juntamente com o sistema o arquivo `.pdb`, para que você tenha nas mensagens capturadas do ELMAH as linhas em que os erros ocorrem dentro do código fonte.

Comment: Obrigado cara, vou verificar e dar uma estudada nele agora.